# Spring JpaRepository save() does not mock using Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am new to Mockito library and stuck somewhere.

Problem is when I mock save method of Spring jpaRepository I always get null. I am using such code in my project but for testing I have made a dummy code for testing. These are my code :

```
// This is the class for which I am making test case
    @Service("deviceManagementService")
    @Scope(BRASSConstants.SCOPE_SESSION)
    @Transactional
    public class DeviceManagementServiceImpl implements DeviceManagementService {

        public String  show(){
            Device device = new Device() ;
            device.setContactName("abc");
            Device deviceEntity = deviceDao.save(device);
            System.out.println(deviceEntity);  // i get this null always Why ???
            return "demo";
        }
    }
```

And the test case I am writing is :

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class DemoTest {

        @InjectMocks
        private DeviceManagementServiceImpl deviceManagementServiceImpl;

        @Mock
        private DeviceDao deviceDao;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void show(){
            Device device = new Device() ;
            Device deviceEntity = new Device() ;
            deviceEntity.setDeviceId(12L);
            Mockito.when(deviceDao.save(device)).thenReturn(deviceEntity);

            Mockito.when(deviceManagementServiceImpl.show()).thenReturn(null) ;
        }

    }
```

If I use something like this

```
Mockito.when(deviceDao.findByDeviceSerialNo("234er")).thenReturn(deviceEntity);
```

Then it works and give me not null object of Device.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: _Then it works and give me not null object of Device._
what is the question again? not null object?

Answer (score 38):

You setup your mock to return something when it receives a given device objet:

```
        Device device = new Device() ;
        Mockito.when(deviceDao.save(device)).thenReturn(deviceEntity);
```

This tells your `deviceDao` mock to return `deviceEntity` when it receives `device` as a parameter to the `save` method.

Mockito uses `equals` for argument matching. This means that if you call `deviceDao.save(x)`, `deviceEntity` will be returned if `x.equals(device)` is true.

Your method:

```
public String  show(){
        Device device = new Device() ;
        device.setContactName("abc");
        Device deviceEntity = deviceDao.save(device);
        System.out.println(deviceEntity);  // i get this null always Why ???
        return "demo";
}
```

This calls `save()` on a new `Device` instance. 
**I highly doubt that this `device` is equal to the one you setup your mock with.**

One way to solve this is to use a broader matcher in your test:

```
Mockito.when(deviceDao.save(any(Device.class)).thenReturn(deviceEntity);
```

Or simply to ensure that the `Device` that you setup your mock with is the same as the one used in your code. I can't provide you with an example since your question does not include the code for `Device.equals()`.

Comment: @WesternGun OffsetDateTime has a valid and okay `equals()` method. I would advise you figure out why you are not receiving the `OffsetDateTime` instance that you are looking for instead of using `any()`.

Comment: Now I see the datetime problem is no more and is irrelevant. But without using `any()`, Mockito just returns me `null` when I tell it to return the created object. Only with `any()`, my jsonpath verification will succeed. Strange.

Comment: @SalmanS `when(device.save(x)).thenReturn(y)` will only return `y` on `.save()` when `x` is passed as a parameter. The way the mock checks if it is indeed `x`, is through `.equals()`. If `x.equals(param)` is false, the mock won't be triggered. You can fix that by either fixing `.equals()` for `Device` or by using `any(Device.class)` which doesn't care about the actual value.

I hope this makes my answer less confusing.

Comment: @GuiSim one more question... Autowired a repository in a TestCase and used .save() method to save... when called for ex. userService.insertSome("ABC") and there is that repository showing null... Please Help

Comment: @SalmanS I'm sorry, I don't understand. Can you reproduce and link to a repository?

Comment: @GuiSim this approach should return this error : When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.

Comment: @dane131 It sounds like you're calling `when` on a method that has multiple parameters. If you use `any(Device.class)` as one of those parameters, you need to provide matchers for all parameters. So for example if you have `doSomething(device, string1, string2)` you'll need to do `doSomething(any(Device.class), eq(string1), eq(string2))`.